# jQuery $(document).ready() and $(window).load() on Firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-hosting

**Prerequsites**

1. Deployed static website on firebase hosting. There is parent page - https://sapcert-d5654.firebaseapp.com. There is child page https://sapcert-d5654.firebaseapp.com/sap-erp.html.
2. There is script **main.js** linked to child page.
3. There is block for document.ready in **main.js** script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("document .ready");
    ...
    //Generate exams lists
    contentGenerator.generateExamsLst(JSON_sap_erp_lst, exLstMainGridSltr, navPnlSubsolListSltr);
});
```

4. There is block for window.load in **main.js** script:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    console.log("document .load");

    console.log("After .load flag is: " + isPurgedExLstMainGridHTML);
    ...
});
```

5. Function *contentGenerator.generateExamsLst()* text:

```js
var contentGenerator = (function () {
    var generateExamsLst = function (json_file, mdl_grid_selector, nav_pnl_selector) {
            ...
            console.log("After data gen flag is: " + isPurgedExLstMainGridHTML);
        });
    };

    ...

    return {
        generateExamsLst: generateExamsLst,
        ...
    };
})();
```

**Behaviour on Google Chrome**

1. Open main page in Chrome.
2. Open browser console via developer tools (F12).
3. Click picture with **ERP** text under it. Child page have been opened.
   There is following text in browser console:

```
document .ready
document .load
After .load flag is: false
After data gen flag is: false
```

4. Refresh page by browser reload button.
   There is following text in browser console:

```
document .ready
After data gen flag is: false
document .load
After .load flag is: false
```

**Behaviour on Mozilla Firefox**

1. Open main page in Chrome.
2. Open browser console via developer tools (F12).
3. Click picture with **ERP** text under it. Child page have been opened.
   There is following text in browser console:

```
document .ready
document .load
After .load flag is: false
After data gen flag is: false
```

4. Refresh page by browser reload button.
   There is following text in browser console:

```
document .ready
document .load
After .load flag is: false
After data gen flag is: false
```

**Questions**

1. Why Chrome browser call first *console.log()* from *$(document).ready()* body, then call *console.log()* from *$(window).load()* body and then call *console.log()* from *contentGenerator.generateExamsLst()* function when we open child page from parent page?
2. Why Chrome browser call this functions in other order when we refresh page (not open from parent page)?
3. Why this behaviour is different in Firefox browser?